# Requiring Angular App

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp, browserify

I'm trying to figure out how to simplify my angular application and the modules it uses. Currently what I do is that I use `browserify` and include the generated file which is `bundle.js` on my case. I have a `main.js` file which contains a lot of `require()` statements like so:

```js
require('angular');

require('./path/to/main');
require('./path/to/angular.module);
require('./path/to/another.angular.module);
...
require('lodash');
```

While this is working I'm having trouble because I need to `require()` each file in order to include it in the bundle javascript file. I recently stumbled upon this [article](https://medium.com/@dickeyxxx/best-practices-for-building-angular-js-apps-266c1a4a6917) specifically using `gulp-concat`. Problem is that I'm not sure how I would include the node modules like `angular` or `lodash` other than using the `<script>` tag.

I thought about using both `browserify` and `gulp-concat` but I can't figure out how I would `require()` the generated file by `gulp-concat`.

I put all processed files in a separate directory as well. I'm up for any ideas too.

Thansk!

Comment: Have a look at [yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) it includes multiple templates for building Angular applications with [bower](http://bower.io/) and [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/).

Comment: Sorry, I already have a lot of things going on with Gulp. Gonna be difficult to switch to Grunt.